# Could Thanos have inadvertently 'snapped' himself out of existence?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war, thanos

Given the power of the unified Infinity Stones, had Thanos decreed half the universe out of existence without specifying himself as an exclusion?

Could he have accidentally wiped himself out?

The previous 'similar' questions referred to everyone else and not the bearer specifically.

The answer of this seemingly similar question [states](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/186933/who-decides-which-half-of-the-universe-should-be-destroyed): "It appears to be determined by the wielder"

But this doesn't answer the question specifically, although it says "...the randomness appears to be true randomness, but this is by conscious design".

But no where do we see Thanos excluding himself from this randomness.

Thus going back to the original question: Could he have ***accidentally*** wiped himself out?

Comment: This question has already been asked [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/192626/thanos-infinity-gauntlet-and-the-big-purge) which was closed as a duplicate of [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/186933/who-decides-which-half-of-the-universe-should-be-destroyed)

Comment: @Edlothiad - I don't think those are dupes. OP is asking if Thanos *excluded* himself from the process, not how the process works.

Comment: The specific being dupes to the general question, @Valorum. If not of the latter question, it should _certainly_ be duped to the former (in my first comment)

Comment: @Edlothiad - Well, there's certainly an argument that the earlier question shouldn't have been closed

Comment: It's not a duplicate.  I'm not asking about which half or anyone else.  Just Thanos since he's the bearer of the stones.

Comment: I believe I already have seen this question, maybe on Movies.SE.

Comment: @Taladris - Indeed. And the answer below is almost identical, albeit with a better source for the quote; https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/88478/was-thanos-really-committed-or-just-a-hypocrite

Comment: I’m not 100% sure it would have been an accident — his original plan on Titan, as he describes it, was a random lottery that didn’t discriminate. Presumably it would have included him. It’s quite possible that his finger snap *did* include him as a potential victim, intentionally. Then again, he did also say that he planned to watch the sun rise on a grateful universe after completing his plan, so maybe he thought he deserved to live to see the results.

Comment: Any way to appeal to the moderators who incorrectly labelled this as a duplicate?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Thanos (probably) included himself in the lottery.

According to a [Q&A session](https://pastebin.com/YdLUxFJD) that the [Russo Brothers gave](https://io9.gizmodo.com/joe-russo-gave-the-infinity-war-answers-youve-been-wait-1825776831), Thanos does appear to have included himself in the random selection process. Note that he's never portrayed as anything other than a *true believer* in his own plan, one that he's literally willing to sacrifice his own children (and himself) in order to fulfil.

> **Q.** *What’s the possibility of Thanos killing himself when he snaps?*
>
> **Russo:** *The possibility of him doing it?*
>
> **Student:** *Yeah*
>
> **Russo:** *As a part of his random execution? **He could’ve- and you can ask if he allowed himself to be a part of that random process. He does have a very interesting look on his face. When we come back to him after the snap, before he disappears, a look of surprise.***