# Why is the Black Order so devoted to Thanos, even if they can also be randomly killed?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war, thanos

In film *Avengers: Infinity War* we see that all members of the Black Order

> are dead when Thanos snaps his fingers. But we can assume that it is possible for them to also randomly disappear after snap if they were still live.

If so - why are they helping him? When Thanos

> snaps his fingers he could also be randomly chosen to die, but he has the Infinity Gauntlet, he can resurrect himself after that. The members of the Black Order couldn't.

Does Thanos ensure that the Black Order will be omitted by his actions or are they rather fanatically devoted to Thanos's mission and also take the option that they disappear? Why somebody knowing Thanos plan and his random killing procedure still want to serve him. What're the benefits?

Do we know any motivation of that devotion in comics?

P.S. It's not question about who decides which half of the universe will die but why people who know this plan and also can be effected by this plan, still want to serve Thanos.

Comment: Mhm. And because of that I wrote: "Does Thanos ensure that the Black Order will be omitted by his actions or are they rather fanatically devoted to Thanos's mission and also take the option that they disappear?"

Comment: They're willing to fight (and die) for him. What makes you think they wouldn't be willing to accept 50/50 odds that his plan would kill them?

Comment: Because maybe this is the motivation - I will fight for You because You swear that I will not be affected by a snap. It's a huge difference between decision that You fighting and assume that You can die during battle, and why You are fighting for.

Comment: And at the risk of answering prematurely, “Why somebody knowing Thanos plan and his random killing procedure still want to serve him. What're the benefits?” — one assumes they believe in the plan. Right at the start of the movie, Ebony Maw tells the dying Asgardians how lucky they are to be giving their lives to a worthy cause. There’s a good chance that [Thanos himself was happy to be part of the selection process](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/194178/could-thanos-have-inadvertently-snapped-himself-out-of-existence), so the Black Order could have felt the same.

Comment: Possible Stockholm syndrome? Maybe they prefer a 50/50 of being dust over the 100% chance of him killing them if they opposed him?

Comment: Death cults aren't usually renowned for their sensible thinking

Comment: A quick clarifying question - are you sure that the Snap killed the surviving members of the Black Order?  Didn't Thor kill all the "grunts" after the named characters had been killed by Bruce Banner, Black Widow, et al?  I always thought that "What did it cost?" "Everything," referred to Thanos' actual losses in the war itself, and not from the Snap.

Comment: @tbrookside The Black Order is the Children of Thanos, the army were the Chitauri and whatnot. All of the Children were killed except Nebula who’d betrayed them.

Answer (score 4):

They believed in Thanos' vision and why he was doing it. Probably somewhat because they have been raised on his ideology as his own children: the group's nickname being the Children of Thanos. However, they do, or in some cases did, believe in his reasons. Gamora even used to and we see this when she talks to Thanos.

> **Thanos:** Little one, it's a simple calculus. This universe is finite, its resources finite. If life is left unchecked, life will cease to exist. It needs correction.
>
> **Gamora:** You don't know that!
>
> **Thanos:** I'm the only one who knows that. At least, I'm the only one with the will to act on it. For a time... you had that same will... as you fought by my side. Daughter.
>
> <sub>*Avengers: Infinity War*</sub>

Note that Thanos also could have been killed in his plan, taken from [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/194180/58193). If he believed he could die, it's not a stretch to imagine that his children also felt the same and felt it to be a worthy sacrifice.

> **Q.** *What’s the possibility of Thanos killing himself when he snaps?*
>
> **Russo:** *The possibility of him doing it?*
>
> **Student:** *Yeah*
>
> **Russo:** *As a part of his random execution? **He could’ve- and you can ask if he allowed himself to be a part of that random process. He does have a very interesting look on his face. When we come back to him after the snap, before he disappears, a look of surprise.***

Ebony Maw certainly seems to think it as more than just worthy to be picked but a privilege to be taken as part of the plan.

> **Ebony Maw:** Hear me, and rejoice. You have had the privilege of being saved by the Great Titan.... You may think this is suffering... no. It is salvation. Universal scales tip toward balance because of your sacrifice. Smile... for even in death, you have become Children of Thanos.
>
> <sub>*Avengers: Infinity War*</sub>

> **Ebony Maw:** Hear me, and rejoice. You are about to die at the hands of the Children of Thanos. Be thankful, that your meaningless lives are now contributing to...
>
> <sub>*Avengers: Infinity War*</sub>

> **Ebony Maw:**  Zehobereians... Choose a side, or die. One side is a revelation. The other, an honor known only to a few. Now go in peace, and meet your Maker.
>
> <sub>*Avengers: Infinity War*</sub>

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party but as we saw in GoTG 1&2, Thanos was raising Gamora and Nebula since they were children to become warriors to grow up and join the Black Order.
He refers to Black Order as his "children" and Proxima refers to him as "father" in the opening scene in [Infinity War](https://youtu.be/pN9ykgplyZc?t=102). Ebony Maw is also obsequious towards Thanos and is afraid to disappoint him.
All of this can suggest that he raised the other members of the Black Order since they were children and he was much more successful at radicalizing them than he was with Nebula and Gamora. They all agree with idea of killing  off half the population in the universe, most likely with themselves also subject to the possibility of death having been radicalized since they were children. There is precedent for such behavior in our world too.

Comment: They know the plan but have been influenced to be okay with being snapped.