# Did Thanos exclude certain alien races from the snap?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

As far as I know, Thanos killed half of a number of alien species before he got the six Infinity Stones and did the rest. The races include:

- Gamora's species
- Nebula's species
- The other children of Thanos's species

We know Thanos can exclude certain beings from the lottery (see [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/186933/who-decides-which-half-of-the-universe-should-be-destroyed)).

Is there any evidence for whether these particular races were excluded from the snap, or did those races end up being cut in half again?

Comment: Drax disappeared and iirc his species was previously culled (hence his hatred for Thanos)...so it would appear that at least his species got cut in half again. Not sure about the others.

Comment: well, Groot disappeared - but I don't remember seeing half of the visible trees of Wakanda disappear. Also, was it half of each species; half of each planet? or just half of all life? Could for example, one planet remain completely untouched, while another is completely wiped out? Did the lottery also include Thanos himself? He was such a true believer, he might well have killed himself as part of the snap.

Comment: @Andrew “was it half of each species; half of each planet? or just half of all life?” — see https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/186884/does-thanos-plan-apply-to-higher-order-beings. “Did the lottery also include Thanos himself?” See https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/194178/could-thanos-have-inadvertently-snapped-himself-out-of-existence

Comment: This has already been asked and answered. Check the answer here regarding those he already culled: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/187369/what-happened-to-the-planets-thanos-already-culled/187460#187460