# Was Thanos immune to the annihilation wave?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war, thanos, the-infinity-gauntlet

In *Avengers: Infinity War* Thanos was building the Infinity Gauntlet to annihilate half of the living beings.

> After he collected all the Infinity Stones, he snapped his fingers and unleashed the wave.

Was he immune to the annihilation, or unleashing it was for Thanos like pulling the trigger in Russian roulette with 50% chance of committing the suicide?

Comment: Annihilation Wave means something very specific in the comics. Why did you choose that term?

Comment: Exact dupe of [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/194178/58193) which is a dupe of [this one](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/186933/58193).

Comment: Thanks for the links to the questions. This one can be closed then.

Comment: The proper term is "the snapture." :D

Comment: @Kai I think that's just a fan term, in-universe it's called "The decimation". Which is kinda funny cause that means to kill 1 in 10, not half.

Comment: @virusbomb I know it's just a "fan term" - - it was a joke. However, I still think it's better than "the decimation." :P

Answer (score 0):

There is no evidence on the film that answers to this question, however, if we assume that in fact this event was created by a wave originated on the Gauntlet, is fairly reasonable to think that the emitting source of the wave is outside of it's area of effect.