Endgame Thanos' Plan
In Avengers: Endgame, Thanos plans to "shred this universe down to its last atom," and then create a new one the way he wants it to be.
I've never seen the obvious question addressed: would this not kill him? And thus extinguish any hope of even a Thanos-approved universe.
I assume Thanos would die in a complete vacuum without anything, and indeed without 3 spatial dimensions in which to subsist, even.
Did he become so delusional and bent on revenge that he did not consider this? Did he assume he would end up on some Astral Plane as we saw in Infinity War?
Is there any indication from other sources what might have happened?

Dupe of: Who decides which half of the universe should be destroyed?.

I think we can reasonably assume that he would exclude himself from this edict, along with whatever support mechanism is required to keep him alive

@Valorum - your own answer contradicts that statement :P - https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/194178

@fez - He "allowed himself" to be part of the lottery, ergo he could have also chosen to exclude himself.

Still seem like contradictory statements to me hahaha

Having all infinity stones under it's control he would be able to "exist out of existence"

I feel like when he said "shred this universe down to its last atom," it wasn't meant as a literal plan, but rather a figurative way of saying he's going to rebuild everything the way he wants.

Can't he just order a single command "grind the universe down and rebuild it"? I don't see the issue. Also in his twisted mind he might be ok with not making it through the experience.
