# Why doesn't Iron Man's action affect this person in Endgame?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, iron-man, avengers-endgame

At the end of *Avengers: Endgame* Iron Man

> snapped his fingers with the Infinity Stones to erase all of the villains.

As Tony does not know

> who Gamora is.

How can she survive this as she was coming with Thanos and was considered as a bad girl in the beginning of the battle?

Comment: Gamora was never seen after Tony's snap so I am not sure where you are getting this from

Comment: So in other words, you’re asking “Why is Gamora?”

Comment: Remember that the only reason they never got the Gauntlet off on Titan was due to Quill sorting out his relationship problems with Thanos.  Tony could recall her name being mentioned then.

Comment: The real question is why he didn't say "wipe out Thanos' forces, and save me so my daughter can have her dad"...but let's not bring THAT up :D.

Comment: As Tony had Soul Stone, the basic assumption of your question is wrong. Tony could easily look into the soul of Gamora to know that she was in his side.

Comment: Tony is cursed with knowledge!

Answer (score 81, accepted):

## How do you know his actions didn't affect her?

Last we see of Gamora is during the battle where she has a little spat with Quill, after that we don't see her. For all we know she does actually survive the battle and Tony's snap.

## Tony might have excluded her anyway

Gamora was seen fighting for the good guys on the field in the battle and Tony at least knows her name because Quill mentioned her multiple times in front of him. It stands to reason that in the off screen time on Titan in *Avengers: Infinity War* he may have described her more to see if they had seen her. As such he may have excluded her.

## Tony might not have seen her

And if the previous point doesn't float your boat Tony might not have seen her in the battle anyway and as such might have excluded her on the grounds of not knowing she was there to be snapped.

## The Stones may have decided

As Paul D. Waite mentions in a comment Tony may have just decided to wipe out Thanos' forces and the Stones/Gauntlet themselves may have decided what constitutes someone working for Thanos. As Gamora had switched sides at this point it may have left her alone.

Comment: Plus we don’t really know how Infinity Gauntlet actions work. Tony might have just said to the gauntlet hey, dissolve Thanos’s forces, okay? And the gauntlet itself might have determined that Gamora was no longer on Thanos’s side.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite True there's some degree of control over the actions but it's not obvious if the wearer has complete and full control.

Comment: I do like the "Stones may have decided" best. It's unlikely that Tony somehow individually identified every entity to get dusted.

Comment: The soul stone does seem to have a certain... wisdom.

Comment: Didn't they show Quill in the end with a picture of Gamora on the screen saying 'Missing' ?

Comment: @Syntax138 I think it was "scanning" for her.

Comment: "Missing" or not-found-by-scanner both mean nothing.  She might be dusted, she might have ran off, she might have been kidnapped by the Kree, she might have been hit by some stray Pym particles and become very tiny.  We have no idea.

Comment: He's definitely heard her name before. "I'll do you one better: WHY is Gamora?"

Comment: He also spent 21 days playing "flick football" with Gamora's sister, so the very few people in the galaxy she ever cared about may have come up as a conversation topic at some point.

Comment: @DanielR.Collins Well, given that the stones are able to follow extremely complex "commands", it seems they are able to perfectly anticipate what meaning the command has. I imagine them as a sufficiently advanced AI, the good kind of genie who actually goes with the spirit of your wish. In the end, they might even ask for every individual action that has to happen - just take the brain of the wisher, and run quadrillions of simulations simultaneously on emulated "hardware". It's the closest you can get to magic without just throwing your hands up and crying "magic!"

Answer (score 74):

**What's Tony got to do with anything?**

Neither did Thanos know half the people in the Universe.  In both Infinity War and Endgame it's implied that the stones are displaying some level of sentience in carrying out complex implementations of simple directives ("Kill half of everybody," "Kill all the bad guys") and that their awareness of the current state of reality includes who's naughty and who's nice - and, as such, would be aware that Gamora switched sides 7 scenes ago.

Comment: I like this answer, though displaying some selectivity doesn't necessarily imply sentience. Databases are not sentient, but given a detailed database to work with the queries to handle the selection for any of the three "snaps" would be fairly simple.

Comment: @TimothyAWiseman I don't disagree, and perhaps "sentience" is the wrong word, but it seems the Stones are capable of discerning circumstances of reality around them without having a DBA import new table data.  The Soul Stone and it's ability to perceive sacrifice and internalize the data of those that are sacrificed is the most drastic example, and perhaps the way the Reality Stone acts through Jane Foster after possessing her.

Comment: Of course, if Tony's command was "dust everyone who doesn't belong in this time" then Gamora's gone.  If it was "dust Thanos and his forces", then she's fine.

Comment: Btw this is how it works in the comics. The owner of the stones gets "cosmic awareness" and therefore could decide for each being individually. Also Hulk mentions he "tried everything" to get Natasha back,  while we only see a finger snap.

Answer (score 19):

The ***Snapper*** decides who lived and who *dusts* out of existence as mentioned in the answer [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/186933/who-decides-which-half-of-the-universe-should-be-destroyed).

Tony couldn't risk killing innocent people in the process. So, this is what his actions could have actually meant: ***"Anyone who's allegiance is towards Thanos should be dusted"***.

Since the past Gamora changed her sides and joined the present-day Nebula, her allegiance towards Thanos ended. This could be the reason why she survived the snap (considering she did survive the snap).

And it's left to the stones (maybe the *Soul Stone* or *Mind Stone*) to identify if she really parted ways from Thanos.

Answer (score 9):

Tony Stark spent a lot of time with Nebula. She might have told him about Gamora. So he definitely knew about her.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  This answer is a bit terse, and is mostly covered by existing answers (although they primarily suggest Quill as the one most like to tell Tony about Gamora).  To make this a good answer you should point to some evidence in the movies where Tony is explicitly made aware of Gamora and that she is on their side.  Please read [answer] for more pointers on writing a good answer.

Comment: @DavidW Thanks for that. I brought my partial reddit experience here. I'll keep that in mind. :)

Answer (score 1):

Gamora was never with Thanos, she was always setting herself up as a control rod to kill him if he ever got close to reaching his ultimate goal. Since she would remain close enough to kill him if she pretended to be loyal she did not have another, better choice to stopping him. Consider her origin the Mad Titan wiped out her mother and half her world then took her. She was playing a very long game to get her personal justice and along the way she was being made stronger and understanding more about his ultimate goal and trying to find a way that she would stop him, she herself. During her personal journey she had to keep closest to him and within his innermost circle of trust which meant completing with Nebula with Zero chance of compassion, as that could jeopardize her mission. Consider meeting up with the Guardian's and taking one or more of the stones out of play the first real chance she had to break out of a lifetime undercover as an evil 'daughter' and show her true self. I'm just amazed Thanos did not realize this at some point, at least enough to know how deep down he failed and thus disqualify the love he thought he had for her, and then regain that love with the respect she maintained for her true purpose - to Kill Thanos/Stop his Infinity Stones quest. I think there was a missed repartee just before he sacrificed her for the soulstone. She could tell him how she really felt, he would get angryish and sad she could then say this disqualified her as a sacrifice, then he would make peace with what he made her and respect her will and love her for it , maybe even more.

Comment: _"For a time... you had that same will... as you fought by my side. Daughter."_ She was with Thanos for a time. And if you take Endgame in to account she only really leaves Thanos' side just before GotG.